# Como eliminar elementos seleccionados de un listiview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, baseadapter

Llevo días intentando eliminar los elementos que yo he seleccionado en un `Listview` por medio de `checkboxs` sin tener éxito. Sólo logre realizar la eliminación total de la lista. Acá va mi código:

item_agenda.java

```
public class Item_agenda {
private String nombre;
private String nombre_contacto;
private String nombre_facebook;
private String nombre_instagram;
private String nombre_twitter;
boolean checked = false;

public Item_agenda() {
    super();
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public String getNombre_contacto() {
    return nombre_contacto;
}

public void setNombre_contacto(String nombre_contacto) {
    this.nombre_contacto = nombre_contacto;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public String getNombre_facebook(){
    return nombre_facebook;
}

public void setNombre_facebook(String nombre_facebook){
    this.nombre_facebook = nombre_facebook;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public String getNombre_instagram(){
    return nombre_instagram;
}

public void setNombre_instagram(String nombre_instagram){
    this.nombre_instagram = nombre_instagram;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public String getNombre_twitter(){
    return nombre_twitter;
}

public void setNombre_twitter(String nombre_twitter){
    this.nombre_twitter = nombre_twitter;
}


public boolean isChecked(){
    return checked;
}

}
```

Adapter_agenda.java

```
public class Adapter_agenda extends BaseAdapter{

protected Activity activity;
protected List<Item_agenda> items;


//CONSTRUCTOR
public Adapter_agenda(Activity activity, List<Item_agenda> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private TextView text;
    private CheckBox check;

}

//Cuenta los elementos
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}
//Devuelve un objeto de una determinada posicion
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public boolean isChecked(int position) {
    return items.get(position).checked;
}


//METODO PRINCIPAL, AQUI SE LLENAN LOS DATOS
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (activity).getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_agenda, null);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_agenda);
        viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.text.setText(items.get(position).getNombre());
    viewHolder.check.setChecked(items.get(position).checked);




    final String itemStr = items.get(position).getNombre();
    viewHolder.text.setText(itemStr);

    viewHolder.check.setTag(position);



    viewHolder.check.setChecked(isChecked(position));

//Devolvemos vista
    return rowView;
}

}
```

//Funcion del MainActivty que realiza la eliminación sólo completa

```
public void eliminar_todo(){
    eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ConstruyeAgenda.this);
            dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");
            dialogo1.setMessage("¿ Esta seguro que desea eliminar este usuario ?");
            dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    lista.clear();
                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ConstruyeAgenda.this, Vincular.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ConstruyeAgenda.this, Vincular.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            dialogo1.show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: En éste enlace está resuelta una duda muy similar a la tuya: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016739/how-to-delete-check-box-items-from-list

Comment: Puedes añadir el codigo completo de tu MainActivity para entender mejor tu codigo.

Comment: Tengo que saber como seleccionas los items con los checkBoxs para darte una respuesta precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que mandar a remover el elemento ya sea por su índice o por el objeto como tal:

```
ArrayList.remove(índice);
```

o

```
ArrayList.remove(elemento);
```

Después haces que el adaptador notifique los cambios:

```
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Aclaración**: Éste código me funciona en Android Studio, no sé si en otros IDE's funcione igual.

Answer (score -1):

Esta eliminando todos los elementos ya que estas eliminado todos los elementos de la lista al dar clic en el botón "Confirmar" del diálogo:

```
 dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    //Elimina todos los elementos del List.
                    lista.clear();
                    //Actualiza datos en Adapter.
                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ConstruyeAgenda.this, Vincular.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

**Para eliminar únicamente los elemento seleccionados**, como tienes en cada objeto `item_agenda` tiene la propiedad:

```
public boolean isChecked(){
    return checked;
}
```

puedes obtener los valores, en caso de ser true se elimina de la lista, al terminar actualizas tu adapter:

```
    dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {

                        //Elimina elementos seleccionados del List.
                        int counter = 0;
                        for(Boolean item : items){
                          if(item) { //true, elimina de la lista.
                            lista.remove(counter);
                          }
                          counter++;
                        }

                        //Actualiza datos en Adapter.
                        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(ConstruyeAgenda.this, Vincular.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

Mira, no se como es tu código para seleccionar los items, pero puedes solucionar tu problema de la siguiente manera.

Crea un ArrayList de tipo int en el que almacenes las posiciones de los items que selecciones. Luego en el evento onClick del botón eliminar recorres ese ArrayList y eliminas los items que se encuentren en las posiciones que se almacenaron en el ArrayList.

Declaras el ArrayList como variable de la clase

```
ArrayList<int> posiciones = new ArrayList<int>();
```

Almacena las posiciones de los items que eliminaras

```
// ...
// Dentro del código que utilizas para seleccionar los items.
posiciones.add(posicion)
//...
```

En el evento onClick del botón eliminar

```
public void eliminar_todo(){
    eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ConstruyeAgenda.this);
            dialogo1.setTitle("Importante");
            dialogo1.setMessage("¿ Esta seguro que desea eliminar este usuario ?");
            dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {

                    // Eliminas los items que se encuentran en las
                    // posiciones almacenadas en el ArrayList
                    for(int posicion : posiciones) {

                        lista.remove(posicion)
                    }

                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ConstruyeAgenda.this, Vincular.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ConstruyeAgenda.this, Vincular.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            dialogo1.show();

        }
    });
}
```